# Generic Variadic Types in Python3+ class definition

Tags: python, types, variadic

I haven't used Python in a while. I'm implementing a simple stack:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self, val) -> None:
        self.stack.append(val)

    def pop(self) -> int:
        return self.stack.pop()
```

My question is about this line - `def pop(self) -> int`, where I've hardcoded the return value as `int`. What if I want my `Stack` to work for lists of any type `list<T>`? I assume `typing.TypeVar` would be useful here? Basically given `self.stack: list<T>` then `pop(self) -> T`. So when I `def __init__(self)` I need to update the Stack to know that its elements are of type `T`?

I hope I've articulated that well enough. This is obviously a toy example but I'm trying to learn more about typed Python 3.

**Note**
This data structure may be unpythonic to begin with, as I suppose lists are not meant to be typed. Any comment or further reading as to why this is and how to think about it would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) with a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.stack.append(val)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.stack.pop()

s = Stack[int]()
x = s.pop()  # Knows x is an 'int'

s.push("hello")  # Expected type 'int' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'str' instead
```